# Ошибка "Too many redirects" в javafx webview при запросе к https

Tags: java, javafx, webview, https

Здравствуйте,

Создаю webview и запрашиваю загрузку страницы.

С "http://" все работает, но с "https://" выводит ошибку

> java.lang.Throwable: Too many redirects

Код простой:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        webEngine.load(url);
      }
    });
}
```

Пытался сохранять куки:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {



        String tmp = toURL(url);
        if (tmp == null) {
          tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
        }

        URI uri = URI.create(tmp);
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        headers.put("Set-Cookie",
                    Arrays.asList("name=value"));
        try {
          CookieHandler.getDefault()
                       .put(uri,
                            headers);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        webEngine.load(tmp);
      }
    });
}
```

Пробовал убрать защиту соединения:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
      public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
      }

      public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

      public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
    }};
    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
      SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
      sc.init(null,
              trustAllCerts,
              new java.security.SecureRandom());
      HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    }

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        webEngine.load(tmp);
      }
    });

}
```

Но так ничего и не получилось.

**Обновление**

Дело в том, что не понятно из-за чего ошибка.

По идее, обычные куки работают. Возможно не работают какие-то защищенные куки у https.

Если ошибка защищенного соединения, то и ошибка должна быть другая, типа не удалось установить соединение.

Возможно, какие-то проблемы с касперским, с его сертификатами которые он подставляет. Но выключал его и все равно ошибка связанная с редиректами.

Возможно, есть способ отследить подробнее ошибку. Куда идут редиректы, из-за чего редиректы.

Самое странное, что компонент, то стандартный, но сколько искал не нашел решения.

Comment: Какая у вас верся jdk?

Comment: (build 1.8.0_112-b15)